# Google GCM and deploying release build APK via email

Tags: android, mono, google-cloud-messaging

I am in the final stages of getting my first android app ready to go out to the play store. To test my final signed release build I emailed the APK to my phone and installed as an 'Unknown App'.

Everything looks to be working fine except my GCM push registration process. I don't seem to be getting a response from google when I try register. If I deploy this same build from my IDE to the phone everything works fine, no code changes at all..

Are their any restrictions on GCM registration? Does the app have to be deployed from the Play store for this process to work?

Any guidance would be great!

Comment: Has the mobile a valid gmail account synced?

Comment: @arcastro not gmail but google account... from doc: `For pre-3.0 devices, this requires users to set up their Google account on their mobile devices. A Google account is not a requirement on devices running Android 4.0.4 or higher.`

Comment: I see, ty for that @Selvin. Adrian, did you manage to register it installing the application from Eclipse?

Comment: No problem for me. I had a gcm app installed via Eclipse IDE on my phone (signed with debug key). I just did an Ant (signed with release key) build. Mailed it to my phone. I had to uninstall the debug signed version first, then installed the release key signed version. It works fine. I guess the regid changes, but as I save that to a database on my owner server, it's not a problem for me.